# Cannot indent for React.js file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using vscode for year. I installed prettier and set auto-format when save. This is the first time I encounter indentation problems when I write React file. I tried to re-set the auto-format settings and searched solutions but none work. It's very frustrating.

[My code before I hit save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5FGv.png)

Indentation all messed up after I press ctrl + s for save. Even I use Shift + Alt + F it doesn't format correctly.
[My code after I hit save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ixka.png)

I got such problems with React.js file only. It's all good for html and css files. Do appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Is it detecting the syntax as vanilla js instead of jsx?

Comment: Thanks Tyler for your reminder. I searched solution which is to rename file to .jsx. But this doesn't fix the problem. Could anyone please help?